# Retrying a failed dynamic import? (SPA/PWA)

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox, dynamic-import

Something that I'm running into with a project I'm working on is, I have a **single page application**. I'm handling browser **navigation routing on the client-side**, that lets me dynamically import some modules whenever a route is matched. My routing setup looks a bit like this:

```js
router.setRoutes([
    {
        path: '/',
        component: 'app-main', // statically loaded
    },
    {
    path: '/posts',
        component: 'app-posts',
        action: () => { import('./app-posts.js').catch(() => Router.go('/offline');} // dynamically loaded
    },
    {
        path: '/offline', network
        component: 'app-offline', // also statically loaded
    }
]);
```

And here's a simple image of the 'app' for clarity:

[image: A simple single page application that has a header, three links: main, posts and offline. And some body content]

I'm caching the app shell in my service worker, which means that the `main` page, and the `offline` page get precached, and the `posts` page should get cached during runtime (once requested, so if the user clicks on the `posts` link)

So my precache manifest caches: `main.js`, `offline.js`, and my `index.html`.

Where I'm hitting a bump is:

- The user loses network connection
- The user tries to go to the `posts` page
- The dynamic import for this may fail if it hasnt been requested and cached before (and the user will be redirected to the `offline` page)

But when my user gains network connectivity again, clicks the `posts` link, the dynamic import will still fail; I'm guessing because the browser dedupes dynamic imports.

Which is a huge shame, because my user has a network connection; this request should succeed! The only way I can figure out how to deal with this is to have the user reload the page, and request the `posts` page again.

So my question is, how should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by checking if the user has network connection before trying to do the import like this:

```js
function handleRoute(url) {
  if('onLine' in navigator) {
    if(navigator.onLine) {
      // user is online, safe to import
      import(url);
    } else {
      // user is offline, don't even try to import -> straight to `/offline`
      Router.go('/offline');
    }
  } else {
    // incase the browser doesnt support `navigator.onLine`, try to import anyway
    import(url);
  }
}
```

It *feels* like a slightly hacky way to do it, but then again [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=navigator.onLine) for `navigator.onLine` is  pretty good.

For more information on retrying failed dynamic imports, I found [this](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import/issues/80) issue in the `tc39/proposal-dynamic-import` github repo.

Comment: That solution is all well and good, but what if your code has already cached the url and you want to dynamically load it when offline?
When I try such a file, while offline, a fetch works fine (and I see workbox messages to say it is serving the file from cache), but an import does not work, giving an error.
It's like the browser is bypassing the service worker altogether for dynamic imports.

Answer (score -2):

The browser is not doing that sort of caching/deduping/whatever. You can verify this easily by calling `import` from the console and toggling your network online/offline.

So the problem is most likely with the framework you're using. The caching of the first call to the route action happens somewhere in the framework. Maybe consult the documentation?

Comment: I did run through the router code with the debugger, and I can verify that the `action` function is called multiple times. Further info, I think the browser _is_ doing some kind of deduping here, smallest reproduction is: `<html>
    <body><button onClick="myFun()">click</button></body>
    <script>function myFun() {import('./my-module.js')}</script>
</html>`, open the network tab, the import will only ever run once